# AngularJS & Laravel - $http POST file to Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I am trying to POST a file along with other form data to my laravel API, I have the exact same code as https://stackoverflow.com/a/25264008

But my Laravel API is not receiving any file at all. However, when I test my API with Postman, it works perfectly.

EDIT (this is the partial code in my laravel API):

```
$file = $request->file('coverphoto');
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$fileName = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8)).'.'.$extension;
$file->move('uploads', $fileName);
$myobj->cover = $fileName;
...
$myobj->save();
```

Comment: What happens if you check in your Networks tab in console ?

Comment: I get status 200 from my API, like usual...

Comment: Not sure if this information is useful to you - when the file is selected, I get this in `Network`: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QKzRXhp`...

Comment: How about response , it has any json in it ?

Comment: No extra json in my response... as expected, this is the correct behaviour