# How to upload file from method using post method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, html

//this is my controller

```
function addFile(file){
        alert("inside add file");
        customerService.uploadCsv(file).then(function(response){
            if(response=="success"){
                alert("file uploaded");
            }else{
                alert("something went wrong");
            }
        },
        function(error){
            alet("error")

        });
    }
```

//this is my service

```
  this.uploadCsv=function(file){
        alert("inside upload csv service ");
        return $http.post('http://localhost:3005/customers/csv').then(function(response){
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        function(error){
            deferred.reject(error);
            return deferred.promise;
        });
    };//end of uploadCsv function
```

I have to send file in key value,key is 'upl' and value is file.I ma taking file from view(html)

Comment: May be these links helpful for you 1. https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs,  2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483873/angularjs-http-post-file-and-form-data

Comment: I did,it working.Thanks Brother

Comment: You can read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs/34506640#34506640

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `formData`, See [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

```js
  this.uploadCsv = function(file) {
    alert("inside upload csv service ");
    
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('upl', file);
    
    $http.post('http://localhost:3005/customers/csv', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': undefined
        }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
          deferred.resolve(response.data);
          return deferred.promise;
        },
        function(error) {
          deferred.reject(error);
          return deferred.promise;
        });
  }; //
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you tagged this post with Node.js. If you're using Node, there is a useful module which make the file upload easy as pie : [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Just add :

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
```

With /uploads already created on the server (name it as you want).

Then if you're using Express for example, just call it with :

```
app.post('/profile', upload.single('fileName'), function (req, res, next) { // code here });
```

At the end don't forget to add the enctype to your form in the view as describe [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) (multipart/form-data for a file check form).

And it's done !