# Sending file through AngularJS + Java Spring - how to communicate

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate, email-attachments

I want to extract the file through HTML and AngularJS to Java Spring with Hibernate. So, for example I've got in my HTML just:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" ng-click="sendMail()">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> Wyślij
</button>
<input type="file" file-upload multiple name="file"/>   
<button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
```

And i guess that's all for HTML.

JS file:

```
$scope.sendMail = function(){  
 $scope.emailData = new EmailData();
 $scope.emailData.to = "konrad@gmail.com";       
 $scope.emailData.from = "emergency@gmail.com";
 $scope.emailData.subject = "Sending maila";
 $scope.emailData.type = "Sending failure";
 $scope.emailData.title = $scope.data.title;
 $scope.emailData.descriptMail = $scope.data.description;
 $scope.emailData.description = "Chrome 5.4.0";

 $http.post("sendemail", $scope.emailData, {headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'} })
 .then(function (response) {         
    $scope.succes =  true;
 },
function(fail) {
    $scope.error = true;
});
```

}

So, how can I get this file which i drop and click add? I wanted, just like with other datas take `$scope.emailData.attachement = "";` to use this in my Spring file.

Example:

in js I've got `$scope.emailData.description = "Chrome 5.4.0";`
and I can get it by spring: 
`private String description; and stuff with getters and setters`

and then I can use it.

I'm not good in Spring and backend (yet), so that's why I am asking you

Comment: Are you attempting to send an email or upload a file?

Comment: I am attempting to send my email but with a file from user (look at html). I can send mail with no problem, but I want to add this one file from user.

Comment: Do you have any code sending to the server yet? If not, you'll probably want to familiarize yourself with the $http service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Comment: And here's a SO answer showing how to post form data (your email properties like to, from, subject, etc) and the file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25264008/769971

Comment: Thank you, this will be great for me to understand this. Yes, I've got a query for sending my email. For example i've got ng-model="data.description" in my textarea and then i've got scope in JS and send it to java.

Question is, can i for example do the same thing with file or not?

Comment: In the SO post I linked, they're using a FormData object. FormData allows you to append a file as well as regular form data: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: I would recommend adding your angular code that talks to your Java side to your original post since that's the important part with respect to your problem.

Comment: Okay I paste a code of js