# To change IFormFile to IList<IFormFile> and sent $http.post request. AngularJS, ASP.NET Core

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

My example works only with one file. I need an array of files. I use angularJS 1.7 and asp.net-core 2.0

HTML

```
 <div class="post">
    <form>
        <textarea ng-model="Headline" name="Headline" rows="2" cols="63" class="form-control"></textarea>

        <textarea ng-model="BodyText" name="BodyText" rows="4" cols="63" class="form-control"></textarea>

        <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile" multiple/>

        <input id="Submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="createPost()" type="submit" value="Пост" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Method creatPost in AgularJs controller

```
 $scope.createPost = function () {
        var model = {
            Headline: $scope.Headline,
            BodyText: $scope.BodyText,
            ImgPost: $scope.myFile
        }
        $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/Blog/create-post/',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined
                },
                data: model,
                transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                        formData.append(key, value);
                    });

                    return formData;
                }
            })
            .then(function onSuccess(response) {
                if (response.data = "Ok") {
                    $window.location.reload();
                }
            })


            .catch(function onError(response) {
                console.log("Error")
            });
    }
```

Model in C#

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string User { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "")]
    public string Headline { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [StringLength(1000, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "")]
    public string BodyText { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime? Date_Time { get; set; }

    public IFormFile ImgPost { get; set; }
```

And a method signature

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("create-post")]
    public async Task<object> PostSaveOnFile(PostViewModel model)
    {
```

How I need to change my model in # public IFormFile ImgPost { get; set; }
And make changes on my angularJS controller and I shoud be able to sent an array of files. Thanks.

As I understood the problem in my derective of fileReader

```
(function (angular) {
    angular.module('app').directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
      return {
         restrict: 'A',
         link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function() {
               scope.$apply(function() {
                  modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
               });
            });
         }
      };
   }]);
})(window.angular);
```

If I will change in my C# model to IList or IEnumerable it will be only the first file. I did nor understand how to change my derective  to array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you need to update `fileModel` directive to set an array of files instead of single file. You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54963528/7775908) but the resulting array will have `FileList` type and I suggest you to convert it to `Array` because it will be more flexible in conjunction with other changes in code

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
  return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function() {
           scope.$apply(function() {
              modelSetter(scope, Array.from(element[0].files));
           });
        });
     }
  };
}]);
```

In order to let ASP.NET Core properly bind an `Array` (or `List`) you need to add all array values with the same key to `FormData`. For instance, if you have

```
public List<string> Strings { get; set; }
```

you will need to append the values with `Strings` key

```
formData.append("Strings", "value1");
formData.append("Strings", "value2");
formData.append("Strings", "value3");
```

So you need to update `transformRequest` function to properly add an array of files to `FormData`

```
function (data, headersGetter) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
        //you could check if value is FileList
        //but your model can hold array of primitive values like ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
        //this single check for Array covers all cases
        //and you don't need to have different check for FileList
        if (value instanceof Array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                formData.append(key, value[i]);
            }
            return;
        }

        formData.append(key, value);
    });

    return formData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I did nor understand how to change my derective to array

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
  return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function() {
           scope.$apply(function() {
              ̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶S̶e̶t̶t̶e̶r̶(̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶,̶ ̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶[̶0̶]̶.̶f̶i̶l̶e̶s̶[̶0̶]̶)̶;̶
              modelSetter(scope, element[0].files);
           });
        });
     }
  };
}]);
```

Change the `modelSetter` call to return an array.

Comment: Did not help. Now in my model ImgPost null in api controller :(