# Empty request with some upload file in php

Tags: php, upload, multipartform-data

I have a little problem about upload files in ajax. I sent a form-data to my backend server. The problem is that sometimes, depending on the files my backend doesn't receive anything. Nothing on `$_REQUEST`, nothing on `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_FILES` or even in `file_get_contents(php://input)`.

I have already tried to put my `memory_limit` to -1 with `post_max_size` to 0 and my `upload_max_filesize` to 16M.

I tried with a small picture, an heavy one and one between the two.
The small failed. The heavy and the other one are good.

Did any of you have a clue about this problem ?

Edit : I'm using angularJS (angular 1.x.x) on my front-end.

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: People can help more if you share the code your using

Comment: Hi thanks, yes I already check them. Nothing on the error logs and nothing weird on the access log  @JayBlanchard

Comment: @ArleighHix my code is nothing more than just showing all the previous variables on my topic and sending a basic form data. (By the way the console developers show that I have sent the request with all the informations)

Comment: Sounds like something in the server configuration is filtering out the post data for some reason.

Comment: Can you do a packet capture to see if the server is receiving what you're sending?

Comment: @Barmar nice one, i'll do that at the works tomorrow !

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the form encoding type to `multipart/form-data`?

```html
<form action="foo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">...
```

You didn't say how you were sending the files to the server via AJAX, but this SO answer [Angularjs $http post file and form data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25264008/70235) would probably be helpful to you.

Comment: That's an excellent question. Indeed my request is in multipart/form-data. Like I said, in some test it's working without any problem. Even if it's not working my developers console show me that my request is perfectly sent.

Sorry about my english.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part in your question where you said some of the files were getting through.

Comment: I'd fire up Fiddler and see whats different between the requests that do, and do not work. Unfortunately, this is probably going to be a maddening problem to solve, and the solution will turn out to be something really simple, and minor :(.