# File Upload using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-fileupload

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="">
    <input ng-model='file' type="file"/>
    <input type="submit" value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

I want to upload an image from local machine and want to read the content of the uploaded file. All this I want to do using AngularJS.

When I try to print the value of `$scope.file` it comes as undefined.

Comment: what about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979712/file-uploader-integration-for-angularjs?rq=1

Comment: See the accepted answer https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/10211532#37040022. It uses `FormData` and `angular-file-model`. To understand how to use `file-model`, see https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/0ZHCsR. It worked for me.

Answer (score 356, accepted):

Some of the answers here propose using `FormData()`, but unfortunately that is a browser object not available in Internet Explorer 9 and below. If you need to support those older browsers, you will need a backup strategy such as using `<iframe>` or Flash.

There are already many Angular.js modules to perform file uploading.  These two have explicit support for older browsers:

- https://github.com/leon/angular-upload - uses iframes as a fallback
- [https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) - uses FileAPI/Flash as a fallback

And some other options:

- https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/
- https://github.com/uor/angular-file
- https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload
- https://github.com/uploadcare/angular-uploadcare

One of these should fit your project, or may give you some insight into how to code it yourself.

Comment: One more solution (IaaS for file uploading): https://github.com/uploadcare/angular-uploadcare

Comment: EggHead has a good video on this - https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-file-uploads

Comment: @fregas, true, but in this case "older" includes IE 9.

Comment: danialfarid/angular-file-upload is renamed to ng-file-upload

Comment: I have a solution myself and I shared it at https://github.com/vikibaarathi/Angular-PHP-Imgur-Upload

Comment: 3 years old answer. IE 9 is DEAD now in 2016.

Comment: I think you should update your answer to have a proper solution instead of pointing to links. That's the way of stack overflow. Otherwise just make that as a comment.

Answer (score 189):

The easiest is to use HTML5 API, namely [`FileReader`](http://jsfiddle.net/f8Hee/1/)

HTML is pretty straightforward:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
<button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
```

In your controller define 'add' method:

```
$scope.add = function() {
    var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
        r = new FileReader();

    r.onloadend = function(e) {
      var data = e.target.result;
      //send your binary data via $http or $resource or do anything else with it
    }

    r.readAsBinaryString(f);
}
```

**Browser Compatibility**

Desktop Browsers

> Edge 12, Firefox(Gecko) 3.6(1.9.2), 
>   Chrome 7, Opera* 12.02, Safari 6.0.2

Mobile Browsers

> Firefox(Gecko) 32,
>   Chrome 3,
>   Opera* 11.5,
>   Safari 6.1

*Note : readAsBinaryString() method is deprecated and [readAsArrayBuffer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) should be used instead.*

Comment: FileReader is a class from standard HTML5 File API http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/. It allows you to read data from file specified in html input element and process it inside `onloadend` callback function. You don't need any library to use this API, its already in your browser (unless you use very old one). Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, there was a typo, `reader` supposed to be `r`, now fixed. You can upload any file extension, you can experiment here http://jsfiddle.net/f8Hee/1/.

Comment: The issue is that I need to upload and then display the content of the excel sheet on the web page using javascript. I do not want to upload it to the server and then fetch the content from the server. If I use readAsDataUrl() then i get the Base64 encoded form of it. But how do I read that to get the excel data?

Comment: Thanks but i got libraries written on GitHub to read and show and the excel data using javascript. Thank you!

Comment: [FileReader.readAsBinaryString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsBinaryString) is deprecated as of 12 July 2012 Working Draft from the W3C.

Comment: You should'nt access DOM with angular. Is a very bad practice.

Comment: @Siderex, not in the controller, but it is totally great to do it from directive. In fact, this is what directives are for. You can read about it in Angular docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @yagger is there a particular reason why your links are referencing FileReaderSync's `readAsArrayBuffer` method (which are only available in web workers) instead of the regular, async [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer)?

Comment: @doldt, no, I used the wrong link. Thanks for bringing this out. Your link is correct.

Comment: @yagger, May I ask how do I decode the binary data in `data` back into an image file and save it in PHP?

Comment: @yagger - My requirement is to pass selected XML files as payload to REST post request. I tried your code on XML file, but the printed data is also printing cahracters for new line, tab, etc... Like /r /n... Could you please tell me how to avoid this.

Comment: I use this and it was necessary to use `$scope.$Apply();` to update my view inside the `onloadend` return function.

Comment: @Gearbox i think probably crate a file on server with the filename that you got on client side

Answer (score 61):

This is the modern browser way, without 3rd party libraries. Works on all the latest browsers.

```
 app.directive('myDirective', function (httpPostFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            element.bind('change', function () {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', element[0].files[0]);
                httpPostFactory('upload_image.php', formData, function (callback) {
                   // recieve image name to use in a ng-src 
                    console.log(callback);
                });
            });

        }
    };
});

app.factory('httpPostFactory', function ($http) {
    return function (file, data, callback) {
        $http({
            url: file,
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).success(function (response) {
            callback(response);
        });
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<input data-my-Directive type="file" name="file">
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) {

// uploads image in the folder images
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $newfilename = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . end($temp);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'images/' . $newfilename);

// give callback to your angular code with the image src name
    echo json_encode($newfilename);
}
```

js fiddle (only front-end)
https://jsfiddle.net/vince123/8d18tsey/31/

Comment: How would you fetch the file in node?

Comment: Any more details? Do you need an `ng-submit` or a form action? This by itself does nothing

Comment: @Emaborsa  hello I added an jsfiddle and made a more complete php code example. It submits the image after the value of the file input has changed so no ng-submit required.

Comment: The perfect simplest solution, but it took me ages to work out how to get my WCF services to cope with the data which was being uploaded.  It's *vital* that you take the data stream, and pass it through something like MultiParser to actually read in the file's data:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23702692/391605  Otherwise you'll be storing raw bytes of "------WebKitFormBoundary
Content-Disposition:... etc.."

Comment: I needed to add property 'transformRequest: angular.identity' to $http request object as shown by Manoy Ojha a litle further down otherwise the Content-Type would not be set properly and the example would not work.

Comment: isn't `attr` misspelled? should it not be `attrs`?

Comment: The `.success` method is [deprecated and removed from AngularJS V1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Answer (score 39):

Below is working example of file upload:

http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvasani/4hqVu/

In this one function called

```
setFiles
```

From View which will update the file array in controller

or

You can check jQuery File Upload using AngularJS

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html

Comment: Hi, i was looking for something through which I can just upload one file and display just below it. However in your example I was not able to do same. Dont mind but I am new to this angularjs and my intention to learn to do this particular objective in a simpler yet robust way.

Comment: Excellent example without using an additional library / extension. Thanks.

Comment: Very helpful, just a note.. this uses File API which doesn't work in IE9 or below.

Comment: Any idea how I get errors from result? Server might trow an error and I would like to display that error message...

Comment: You can check response in from
xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false)

uploadFailed is a callback function which is already written @
http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvasani/4hqVu/

Comment: Can you show the rest service method on the back end that would take the file as a parameter and store it in some directory?

Answer (score 17):

You can achieve nice file and folder upload using [flow.js](https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js).

https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow

Check out a demo here

http://flowjs.github.io/ng-flow/

It doesn't support IE7, IE8, IE9, so you'll eventually have to use a compatibility layer

https://github.com/flowjs/fusty-flow.js

Comment: `flow.js' is fantastic, but is poor of documentation yet. I need manipulate a single upload and add preview and also send event button separated but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 14):

Use the `onchange` event to pass the input file element to your function.

`<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileSelected(this)" />`

So when a user selects a file, you have a reference to it without the user needing to click an "Add" or "Upload" button.

```
$scope.fileSelected = function (element) {
    var myFileSelected = element.files[0];
};
```

Comment: This is not working as desired.

This is my workflow: 
1. Refresh the page
2. Add new file. ** First file added is always undefined.**
3. Add another file. From now on, every file uploaded is the previous file that I did add. So for the 2nd file that I add, this would upload the first file that I added(which actually failed)

Comment: the best method!

Answer (score 12):

I tried all alternatives that @Anoyz (Correct answer) gives... and the best solution is https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

Some Features:

- Progress
- Multifiles
- Fields
- Old browsers (IE8-9)

It's work fine for me. You just have to pay attention to instructions.

*In server-side i use NodeJs, Express 4 and Multer middleware to manage multipart request.*

Comment: How do you show images? From backend, they are successfully going in, but they are getting saved as `nlzt9LJWRrAZEO3ZteZUOgGc` but without the .png format. How to add that?

Answer (score 9):

### HTML

```
<html>
    <head></head>

<body ng-app = "myApp">

  <form ng-controller = "myCtrl">
     <input type = "file" file-model="files" multiple/>
     <button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
     <li ng-repeat="file in files">{{file.name}}</li>
  </form>
```

### Scripts

```
  <script src = 
     "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
           restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              element.bind('change', function(){
              $parse(attrs.fileModel).assign(scope,element[0].files)
                 scope.$apply();
              });
           }
        };
     }]).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){


       $scope.uploadFile=function(){
       var fd=new FormData();
        console.log($scope.files);
        angular.forEach($scope.files,function(file){
        fd.append('file',file);
        });
       $http.post('http://localhost:1337/mediaobject/upload',fd,
           {
               transformRequest: angular.identity,
               headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}                     
            }).success(function(d)
                {
                    console.log(d);
                })         
       }
     }]);

  </script>
```

Answer (score 9):

The `<input type=file>` element does not by default work with the [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel). It needs a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

### Working Demo of `select-ng-files` Directive that Works with `ng-model`<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43074638/5535245)</sup>

```js
angular.module("app",[]);

angular.module("app").directive("selectNgFiles", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var files = elem[0].files;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <h1>AngularJS Input `type=file` Demo</h1>
    
    <input type="file" select-ng-files ng-model="fileList" multiple>
    
    <h2>Files</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="file in fileList">
      {{file.name}}
    </div>
  </body>
```

---

### `$http.post` from a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)

```
$scope.upload = function(url, fileList) {
    var config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                   transformResponse: angular.identity
                 };
    var promises = fileList.map(function(file) {
        return $http.post(url, file, config);
    });
    return $q.all(promises);
};
```

When sending a POST with a [File object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), it is important to set `'Content-Type': undefined`. The [XHR send method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) will then detect the [File object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and automatically set the content type.

Answer (score 7):

Easy with a directive

Html:

```
<input type="file" file-upload multiple/>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('fileUpload', function () {
return {
    scope: true,        //create a new scope
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        el.bind('change', function (event) {
            var files = event.target.files;
            //iterate files since 'multiple' may be specified on the element
            for (var i = 0;i<files.length;i++) {
                //emit event upward
                scope.$emit("fileSelected", { file: files[i] });
            }                                       
        });
    }
};
```

In the directive we ensure a new scope is created and then listen for changes made to the file input element. When changes are detected with emit an event to all ancestor scopes (upward) with the file object as a parameter.

In your controller:

```
$scope.files = [];

//listen for the file selected event
$scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {            
        //add the file object to the scope's files collection
        $scope.files.push(args.file);
    });
});
```

Then in your ajax call:

```
data: { model: $scope.model, files: $scope.files }
```

http://shazwazza.com/post/uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-angular-js/

Answer (score 7):

i think this is the angular file upload:

### ng-file-upload

Lightweight Angular JS directive to upload files.

Here is the [DEMO](https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/) page.Features

- Supports upload progress, cancel/abort upload while in progress, File drag and drop (html5), Directory drag and drop (webkit), CORS, PUT(html5)/POST methods, validation of file type and size, show preview of selected images/audio/videos.
- Cross browser file upload and FileReader (HTML5 and non-HTML5) with Flash polyfill FileAPI. Allows client side validation/modification before uploading the file
- Direct upload to db services CouchDB, imgur, etc... with file's content type using Upload.http(). This enables progress event for angular http POST/PUT requests.
- Seperate shim file, FileAPI files are loaded on demand for non-HTML5 code meaning no extra load/code if you just need HTML5 support.
- Lightweight using regular $http to upload (with shim for non-HTML5 browsers) so all angular $http features are available

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Answer (score 6):

Your file and json data uploading at the same time .

```js
// FIRST SOLUTION
 var _post = function (file, jsonData) {
            $http({
                url: your url,
                method: "POST",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("model", angular.toJson(data.model));
                    formData.append("file", data.files);
                    return formData;
                },
                data: { model: jsonData, files: file }
            }).then(function (response) {
                ;
            });
        }
// END OF FIRST SOLUTION

// SECOND SOLUTION
// If you can add plural file and  If above code give an error.
// You can try following code
 var _post = function (file, jsonData) {
            $http({
                url: your url,
                method: "POST",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("model", angular.toJson(data.model));
                for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                    // add each file to
                    // the form data and iteratively name them
                    formData.append("file" + i, data.files[i]);
                }
                    return formData;
                },
                data: { model: jsonData, files: file }
            }).then(function (response) {
                ;
            });
        }
// END OF SECOND SOLUTION
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `FormData` object which is safe and fast:

```
// Store the file object when input field is changed
$scope.contentChanged = function(event){
    if (!event.files.length)
        return null;

    $scope.content = new FormData();
    $scope.content.append('fileUpload', event.files[0]); 
    $scope.$apply();
}

// Upload the file over HTTP
$scope.upload = function(){
    $http({
        method: 'POST', 
        url: '/remote/url',
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
        data: $scope.content,
    }).success(function(response) {
        // Uploading complete
        console.log('Request finished', response);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please also explain where 'contentChanged' is used exactly?

Comment: When a file input changes,  triggering this funtion will start upload process.

Comment: Since there's no `<input type="file" ng-change="contentChanged($event)">`, how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvasani/4hqVu/ works fine in chrome and IE (if you update CSS a little in background-image).
This is used for updating progress bar:

```
 scope.progress = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total)
```

but in FireFox angular's [percent] data is not updated in DOM successfully,although files are uploading successfully.

Comment: For FF you can listen to `load` event and if the length is computable then fire a progress event to indicate the successful upload. https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload already takes care of that.

Comment: It's there, but in given fiddle also it's checked and applied. Still no hope in FF.

Comment: I think if you just call uploadProgress inside uploadComplete it should work for FF

Comment: NO it doesn't, and even if it does can you please explain why? I've give  a link to fiddle in my post. If possible can you please update it to working in FF and comment solution's link here?

Comment: What version of Firefox?

Answer (score 3):

You may consider IaaS for file upload, such as [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com/). There is an Angular package for it: https://github.com/uploadcare/angular-uploadcare

Technically it's implemented as a directive, providing different options for uploading, and manipulations for uploaded images within the widget:

```html
<uploadcare-widget
  ng-model="object.image.info.uuid"
  data-public-key="YOURKEYHERE"
  data-locale="en"
  data-tabs="file url"
  data-images-only="true"
  data-path-value="true"
  data-preview-step="true"
  data-clearable="true"
  data-multiple="false"
  data-crop="400:200"
  on-upload-complete="onUCUploadComplete(info)"
  on-widget-ready="onUCWidgetReady(widget)"
  value="{{ object.image.info.cdnUrl }}"
 />
```

More configuration options to play with: https://uploadcare.com/widget/configure/

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a late entry but I have created a simple upload directive. Which you can get working in no time!

```
<input type="file" multiple ng-simple-upload web-api-url="/api/Upload" callback-fn="myCallback" />
```

[ng-simple-upload](https://github.com/shammelburg/ng-simple-upload) more on Github with an example using Web API.

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="file" name='file' onchange="angular.element(this).scope().profileimage(this)" />
```

add 'profileimage()' method to your controller

```
    $scope.profileimage = function(selectimage) {
      console.log(selectimage.files[0]);
 var selectfile=selectimage.files[0];
        r = new FileReader();
        r.onloadend = function (e) {
            debugger;
            var data = e.target.result;

        }
        r.readAsBinaryString(selectfile);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be an update/comment to @jquery-guru's answer but as I don't have enough rep it will go here. It fixes the errors that are now generated by the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/vzhrqotw/

The change is basically:

```
FileUploadCtrl.$inject = ['$scope']
function FileUploadCtrl(scope) {
```

To:

```
app.controller('FileUploadCtrl', function($scope)
{
```

Feel free to move to a more appropriate location if desired.

Answer (score 2):

I've read all the thread and the HTML5 API solution looked the best. But it changes my binary files, corrupting them in a manner I've not investigated. The solution that worked perfectly for me was :

HTML :

```
<input type="file" id="msds" ng-model="msds" name="msds"/>
<button ng-click="msds_update()">
    Upload
</button>
```

JS:

```
msds_update = function() {
    var f = document.getElementById('msds').files[0],
        r = new FileReader();
    r.onloadend = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        console.log(data);
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', data);
        fd.append('file_name', f.name);
        $http.post('server_handler.php', fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
            console.log('success');
        })
        .error(function(){
            console.log('error');
        });
    };
    r.readAsDataURL(f);
}
```

Server side (PHP):

```
$file_content = $_POST['file'];
$file_content = substr($file_content,
    strlen('data:text/plain;base64,'));
$file_content = base64_decode($file_content);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to upload files using AngularJS by using below code:

The `file` for the argument that needs to be passed for the function `ngUploadFileUpload` is `$scope.file` as per your question.

The key point here is to use `transformRequest: []`. This will prevent $http with messing with the contents of the file.

```
       function getFileBuffer(file) {
            var deferred = new $q.defer();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
            }
            reader.onerror = function (e) {
                deferred.reject(e.target.error);
            }

            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        function ngUploadFileUpload(endPointUrl, file) {

            var deferred = new $q.defer();
            getFileBuffer(file).then(function (arrayBuffer) {

                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: endPointUrl,
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        'X-RequestDigest': spContext.securityValidation,
                        "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
                    },
                    data: arrayBuffer,
                    transformRequest: []
                }).then(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }, function (error) {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                    console.error("Error", error)
                });
            }, function (error) {
                console.error("Error", error)
            });

            return deferred.promise;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Above accepted answer is not browser compatible. If some one has compatibility issue try this.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8Hee/429/)

View Code

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
      <br>
      <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
      <p>{{data}}</p>
    </div>
```

Controller code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = 'none';    
    $scope.add = function(){
      var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
          r = new FileReader();
      r.onloadend = function(e){        
          var binary = "";
var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
var length = bytes.byteLength;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
}

$scope.data = (binary).toString();

          alert($scope.data);
      }
      r.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**in simple words**

***in Html -***  add below code only

```
     <form name="upload" class="form" data-ng-submit="addFile()">
  <input type="file" name="file" multiple 
 onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadedFile(this)" />
 <button type="submit">Upload </button>
</form>
```

***in the controller*** -  This function is called when you click **"upload file button"**. it will upload the file. you can console it.

```
$scope.uploadedFile = function(element) {
$scope.$apply(function($scope) {
  $scope.files = element.files;         
});
}
```

***add more in controllers*** - below code add into the function . This function is called when you click on  button which is used  **"hitting the api (POST)"**. it will send file(which uploaded) and form-data to the backend .

```
var url = httpURL + "/reporttojson"
        var files=$scope.files;

         for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
         {
            var fd = new FormData();
             angular.forEach(files,function(file){
             fd.append('file',file);
             });
             var data ={
              msg : message,
              sub : sub,
              sendMail: sendMail,
              selectUsersAcknowledge:false
             };

             fd.append("data", JSON.stringify(data));
              $http.post(url, fd, {
               withCredentials : false,
               headers : {
                'Content-Type' : undefined
               },
             transformRequest : angular.identity
             }).success(function(data)
             {
                  toastr.success("Notification sent successfully","",{timeOut: 2000});
                  $scope.removereport()
                   $timeout(function() {
                    location.reload();
                }, 1000);

             }).error(function(data)
             {
              toastr.success("Error in Sending Notification","",{timeOut: 2000});
              $scope.removereport()
             });
        }
```

in this case .. i added below code as form data

```
var data ={
          msg : message,
          sub : sub,
          sendMail: sendMail,
          selectUsersAcknowledge:false
         };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="csv_file_form" ng-submit="submit_import_csv()" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input ng-model='file' type="file"/>
    <input type="submit" value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

In angularJS controller

```
$scope.submit_import_csv = function(){

        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("csv_file_form"));
        console.log(formData);

        $.ajax({
            url: "import",
            type: 'POST',
            data:  formData,
            mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(result, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
            console.log(result);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have used HTML, CSS and AngularJS. Following example shows about how to upload the file using AngularJS.

```
<html>

   <head>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body ng-app = "myApp">

      <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
         <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
         <button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
      </div>

      <script>
         var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

         myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
            return {
               restrict: 'A',
               link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                  var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                  var modelSetter = model.assign;

                  element.bind('change', function(){
                     scope.$apply(function(){
                        modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                     });
                  });
               }
            };
         }]);

         myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
            this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
               var fd = new FormData();
               fd.append('file', file);

               $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                  transformRequest: angular.identity,
                  headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
               })

               .success(function(){
               })

               .error(function(){
               });
            }
         }]);

         myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
            $scope.uploadFile = function(){
               var file = $scope.myFile;

               console.log('file is ' );
               console.dir(file);

               var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
               fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
            };
         }]);

      </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This comes from [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm), but at least you did the good job of correcting their example, which can't even run because of obvious mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

**Working Example** using Simple Directive (**ng-file-model**):

```
.directive("ngFileModel", [function () {
  return {
      $scope: {
          ngFileModel: "="
      },
      link: function ($scope:any, element, attributes) {
          element.bind("change", function (changeEvent:any) {
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                  $scope.$apply(function () {
                      $scope.ngFileModel = {
                          lastModified: changeEvent.target.files[0].lastModified,
                          lastModifiedDate: changeEvent.target.files[0].lastModifiedDate,
                          name: changeEvent.target.files[0].name,
                          size: changeEvent.target.files[0].size,
                          type: changeEvent.target.files[0].type,
                          data: changeEvent.target.files[0]
                      };
                  });
              }
              reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
          });
      }
  }
}])
```

and use `FormData` to upload file in your function.

```
var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("document", $scope.ngFileModel.data)
 formData.append("user_id", $scope.userId)
```

all credits go for 
https://github.com/mistralworks/ng-file-model

I have faced a small probelm you can check it here:
[https://github.com/mistralworks/ng-file-model/issues/7](https://github.com/mistralworks/ng-file-model)

Finally,here's a forked repo: https://github.com/okasha93/ng-file-model/blob/patch-1/ng-file-model.js

Answer (score 0):

**The code will helps to insert file**

```
<body ng-app = "myApp">
<form ng-controller="insert_Ctrl"  method="post" action=""  name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    <div>
        <p><input type="file" ng-model="myFile" class="form-control"  onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadedFile(this)">
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="(myForm.myFile.$error.required&&myForm.myFile.$touched)">Select Picture</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" name="submit"  ng-click="uploadFile()" class="btn-primary" ng-disabled="myForm.myFile.$invalid" value="insert">
    </div>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="insert.js"></script>
</body>
```

**insert.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.service('uploadFile', ['$http','$window', function ($http,$window) {
    this.uploadFiletoServer = function(file,uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(data){
            alert("insert successfull");
            $window.location.href = ' ';//your window location
        })
        .error(function(){
            alert("Error");
        });
    }
}]);
app.controller('insert_Ctrl',  ['$scope', 'uploadFile', function($scope, uploadFile){
    $scope.uploadFile = function() {
        $scope.myFile = $scope.files[0];
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        var url = "save_data.php";
        uploadFile.uploadFiletoServer(file,url);
    };
    $scope.uploadedFile = function(element) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
                $scope.files = element.files;
                $scope.src = event.target.result  
            });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
    }
}]);
```

**save_data.php**

```
<?php
    require "dbconnection.php";
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $image = time().'.'.$ext;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/".$image);
    $query="insert into test_table values ('null','$image')";
    mysqli_query($con,$query);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this works

file.html

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-app = "app">
      <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
         <input type = "file" file-model = "myFile"/>
         <button ng-click = "uploadFile()">upload me</button>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script src="controller.js"></script>
</html>
```

controller.js

```
     var app = angular.module('app', []);

     app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
           var fd = new FormData();
           fd.append('file', file);

           $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
              transformRequest: angular.identity,
              headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
           }).success(function(res){
                console.log(res);
           }).error(function(error){
                console.log(error);
           });
        }
     }]);

     app.controller('fileCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
        $scope.uploadFile = function(){
           var file = $scope.myFile;

           console.log('file is ' );
           console.dir(file);

           var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload.php";  // upload url stands for api endpoint to handle upload to directory
           fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
        };
     }]);

  </script>
```

fileupload.php

```
  <?php
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $image = time().'.'.$ext;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],__DIR__. ' \\'.$image);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPLOAD FILES

```
<input type="file" name="resume" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadResume()" ng-model="fileupload" id="resume" />


        $scope.uploadResume = function () { 
            var f = document.getElementById('resume').files[0];
            $scope.selectedResumeName = f.name;
            $scope.selectedResumeType = f.type;
            r = new FileReader();

            r.onloadend = function (e) { 
                $scope.data = e.target.result;
            }

            r.readAsDataURL(f);

        };
```

DOWNLOAD FILES:

```
          <a href="{{applicant.resume}}" download> download resume</a>

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

            app.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
                $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data|chrome-extension):/);
                $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data|chrome-extension):/);

            }]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
app.directive('ngUpload', function () {   
  return {    
    restrict: 'A',  
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      var options = {};
      options.enableControls = attrs['uploadOptionsEnableControls'];

      // get scope function to execute on successful form upload
      if (attrs['ngUpload']) {

        element.attr("target", "upload_iframe");
        element.attr("method", "post");

        // Append a timestamp field to the url to prevent browser caching results
        element.attr("action", element.attr("action") + "?_t=" + new Date().getTime());

        element.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        element.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");

        // Retrieve the callback function
        var fn = attrs['ngUpload'].split('(')[0];
        var callbackFn = scope.$eval(fn);
        if (callbackFn == null || callbackFn == undefined || !angular.isFunction(callbackFn))
        {
          var message = "The expression on the ngUpload directive does not point to a valid function.";
          // console.error(message);
          throw message + "\n";
        }                      

        // Helper function to create new  i frame for each form submission
        var addNewDisposableIframe = function (submitControl) {
          // create a new iframe
          var iframe = $("<iframe id='upload_iframe' name='upload_iframe' border='0' width='0' height='0' style='width: 0px; height: 0px;
border: none; display: none' />");

          // attach function to load event of the iframe
          iframe.bind('load', function () {

              // get content - requires jQuery
              var content = iframe.contents().find('body').text();

              // execute the upload response function in the active scope
              scope.$apply(function () { callbackFn(content, content !== "" /* upload completed */); });

              // remove iframe
              if (content != "") // Fixes a bug in Google Chrome that dispose the iframe before content is ready.
                setTimeout(function () { iframe.remove(); }, 250);


              submitControl.attr('disabled', null);
              submitControl.attr('title', 'Click to start upload.');
            });

          // add the new iframe to application
          element.parent().append(iframe);
        };

        // 1) get the upload submit control(s) on the form (submitters must be decorated with the 'ng-upload-submit' class)
        // 2) attach a handler to the controls' click event
        $('.upload-submit', element).click(
          function () {

            addNewDisposableIframe($(this) /* pass the submit control */);

            scope.$apply(function () { callbackFn("Please wait...", false /* upload not completed */); });



            var enabled = true;
            if (options.enableControls === null || options.enableControls === undefined || options.enableControls.length >= 0) {
              // disable the submit control on click
              $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              enabled = false;
            }

            $(this).attr('title', (enabled ? '[ENABLED]: ' : '[DISABLED]: ') + 'Uploading, please wait...');

            // submit the form
            $(element).submit();
          }
        ).attr('title', 'Click to start upload.');
      }
      else
        alert("No callback function found on the ngUpload directive.");     
    }   
  }; 
});



<form class="form form-inline" name="uploadForm" id="uploadForm"
ng-upload="uploadForm12"  action="rest/uploadHelpFile"  method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-top: 3px;margin-left:
6px"> <button type="submit" id="mbUploadBtn" class="upload-submit"
ng-hide="true"></button> </form>

@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadHelpFile", method =
RequestMethod.POST)   public @ResponseBody String
uploadHelpFile(@RequestParam(value = "file") CommonsMultipartFile[]
file,@RequestParam(value = "fileName") String
fileName,@RequestParam(value = "helpFileType") String
helpFileType,@RequestParam(value = "helpFileName") String
helpFileName) { }
```

Comment: please format your answer it is not in proper format