# Update View AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm really having some trouble figuring out how to update the view in AngularJS - just started learning it a few weeks ago, so please go easy. Here's what I'm trying to do: I have a grid of photos that are all being loaded as resources of a factory.

**services.js**

```
appName.factory('Photo', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource('http://localhost:3000/json', {}, {
            query: { method:'GET', isArray:true }
        });
    }
]);
```

Easy enough. So now I want to enable uploading new photos. I'm using the `$http` object to create an AJAX call and then on success trying to update the grid.

**controllers.js**

```
appName.controller('photogrid', ['$scope', 'Photo',
    function($scope, Photo) {
        $scope.photos = Photo.query();
        console.log($scope.photos);
    }
])

appName.controller('uploadFile', ['$scope', '$http', 'Photo',
    function($scope, $http, Photo) {

        $scope.uploadFile = function(form) {

            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('title', form.title.value);
            data.append('description', form.description.value);
            data.append('location', form.location.value);
            data.append('uploadfile', form.fileupload.files[0]);

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/new',
                data: data,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}, 
                transformRequest: angular.identity
            })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                form.reset();
                $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');
                console.log($scope.photos);
                $scope.photos = Photo.query();
                $scope.$apply();
            });

        };
    }
])
```

**view.html**

```
<ul id="photoGrid">
    <li ng-repeat="photo in photos">
        <img ng-src="{{ photo.src }}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried building out a new instance of the `Photo` model and using the `push()` method (`$scope.photos.push(newPhoto)`), but that didn't work. If I do that, I can seem to get another resource added to Photo, but then it still doesn't update on the view. I'm not sure what I'm missing - it's probably something simple.

Comment: Maybe this will help [File Upload using angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)

Comment: Thanks @lukpaw, but that part is already done (with the exception of drag and drop) - I'm looking for information on updating the view after the upload. `$scope.photos` is updated with the additional resource when I do a `console.log` after the AJAX call, but the view doesn't actually update until the page is refreshed.