# Saving attachment to server angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I have been looking this up and cant seem to find any decent tutorials, they all seem convoluted or the information just isnt there. Im looking for a way to save an attachment from the website(i.e. jpg image) and save it as a specific name within the server, as in i will be saving the file to the server with a specific name(i.e. John@john.com/1234.jpg). However i cannot find really any information on how to store an image file within a server using js or angularjs. Could anyone help at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs

Comment: Duplicate doesn't mean it's your question.  It means that the referenced question potentially answers the same problem.  You're looking for a way to upload files to a server using angularjs.  The referenced question would appear to answer that problem.  Perhaps I misunderstood what you're trying to accomplish.