# Angular IE9 fileupload is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I use this way to upload file:

```
  <input type="file" 
         name="upload-file" 
         ng-model= "excelFile" 
         accept=".xlsx" 
         onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileChanged(this);"
         required="true" 
  />
```

Create the fileChanged method in the controller

```
 $scope.fileChanged = function(files) {
     $scope.excelFile = files[0];
 };
```

It works in FireFox, Chrome IE10, IE11, but in IE9 it shows that the "files is null our undefined".

Comment: Are you uploading to the same domain or are you making a `cross-origin-request`?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=file - the file API's you are probably trying to use don't work on IE9. You're going to have to find a library that comes with a shim to make it work.

Comment: I've used this library for file uploads and it works very well. There is a sample using AngularJS: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Try Dropzone.js, http://www.dropzonejs.com/, it's a very useful library.

Comment: @LeeWillis this sample is not working in ie9

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue when uploading image files. It worked fine in IE10 and later versions.
Any version below 10 , file upload is not working. Refer this link

IE9Issue : [File Upload using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to use IE9 and below with the your method. You have two possible ways:
1. Use Flash uploader in case of IE9 and lower. Try to avoid this scenario
2. Use the http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ which will give you "some sort" of file access, as HTML 5 does :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned any method of file upload that uses FormData and File API stuff won't work in IE9 as they aren't available until IE10.

However, two angular modules that have a fallback method that will work with IE9 for uploading files that I know of are:

- [nervgh/angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)
- [danielfarid/angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload): however, it requires Flash to be installed for IE9 uploads

I am using nervgh/angular-file-upload as it does not require Flash.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because in IE the event is in window.event, not passed in as parameter to the event handler. Therefore, the '`this`' will be the doc root or undefined on IE.

You can easily test it by placing `console.log(this)` in event handler on IE. Check out the Event differences section in [this article](http://www.navioo.com/ajax/diferences.php#Event_differences).

I think you can use a native angular directive ng-change, or just

```
$scope.$watch('excelFile', function(newVal){
// implementation
})
```

in the scope.