# AngularJS - How can I bind an input[type=file] to my $scope (IE9 support)?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-scope, typescript, nancy

I would like to be able to do the following in my controller (Note* I'm using TypeScript):

```
disclosure.disclosureDocument = $scope.document;
```

where `disclosure` is my model.  However, this doesn't work as explained [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375).

My question is there a simple way to bind my `input[type=file]` to `$scope` so that I may assign it to my model and pass it through `Nancy` and to my back-end?  If more information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Did you have read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472254/angular-ie9-fileupload-is-not-working ?

Answer (score 0):

neat way of dealing with models is not to assign everything in scope rather assign a instance of controller to scope variable and use in view

```
class fooController  {

   public fooModel;
   static $inject = ['$scope'];
   constructor(scope){

   this.fooModel ='hello world'
   //assign instance to a scope variable and access in view
   scope.vm=this
  }
}
```

and in view

```
  <div>{{vm.fooModel}}</div>
```