# how to send a file from front end to back end with javascript or angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

some one knows how to send a file in an ajax request? my current problem is that i have the URL of the file in a

```html
<input type="file" />
```

but i don't know how to "load" the file in a variable or js object to can send it to my server

Can someone who has done this help me ? if there is any way to do it with AngularJS it would be great

Comment: `<input type="file">` is not for URLs. If you have an URL, use `<input type="url">` (HTML5) or plain `<input type="text">`. Send the URL unchanged to the server, and let the server download it. If you in fact have a *file* (and not a file URL) in a `<input type="file">` element, you'll use `FormData` to get the file contents into the AJAX request; you will also have to handle them at serverside, which is very language-dependent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File Upload using angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)

Comment: @HåkanFahlstedt duplicate - exactly like something else, especially through having been copied.  This isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

Comment: Thanks to all i solve it using a form and sending the post, i know this isn´t ajax but at the end was accepted for the project, thaks to all

Answer (score 1):

Well you have two options to do so

1. by converting to base64 but you can only send a max of 2mb data with it
2. with form data, convert your data to multipart/form-data to do so
   you can use form data

   ```
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('file-name', $(file-content);
   ```