# What is the official/standard way to upload a file?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

There a lots of 3rd party libraries for uploading files, and posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs) that name them, but is there a way to upload a file using only the angularjs SDK?

None of the tutorials I've found show how to do it.

Comment: Just make POST request with FormData. That's it. 5 lines of code.

Comment: @dfsq surely those 5 lines would be bundled as a standard action somewhere

Comment: Unfortunately there is no built-in shortcut in Angular. But work with forms in general in Angular is pretty weak spot. So..

Comment: easy one, sit back and watch https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-file-uploads