# Uploading Video using Angularjs and Symfony2

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, symfony, file-upload

What is the best way to upload video with AngularJS and Symfony2 using MongoDB database, and more scalable to do the upload in the database or in the application files?

Answer (score 2):

Video is only file, so you can use any module mentioned here: [File Upload using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)

If you want to implement it itself, you might like [resumablejs.com](http://resumablejs.com).

For videos I would go with file system, it will probably be better for streaming video.

As for scaling, it depends on your point of view. 
i.e. If your app is running on multiple machines connected to 1 DB than file system is not good idea.

Comment: Well, actually a file system would be a good idea, that file system would obviously reside on a streaming server (one specially designed for handling streaming content) then would be replicated by CDNs. That is how the top companies do it.