# Append an image to form input via AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, forms, form-data

I want to append an image to a form input-Tag by clicking on it. So we have a HTML-Form that looks like this:

```
<form name="upload">
   <input type="file" name="file"/>
</form>
```

On the Page there are severall images displayed. If i´m clicking on of the images, the following function is beeing called and gives it the $event-parameter (which works fine).

```
$scope.uploadTest = function(event){
        var file = event.target;
        var place = document.forms['upload'].files[0];
        place.appendChild(file);
    };
```

The function should take the event.target (which is an image) and appends it to the input formular dynamically. Can some help me? What am I doing wrong? I´ve tried it in any possible way, like appending the image to "document.forms['upload']" or "document.getElementById("file")", but nothing works for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ng input file is not allowed for use ng-model.

> Not every feature offered is available for all input types. Specifically, data binding and event handling via ng-model is unsupported for input[file].

[Detail](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input).

You can take **file path** and use with Jquery File Upload functions.

This will help you:
[File Upload using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)