# upload progress bar with button click in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on image upload with image preview.I want to show the progress bar when the upload button is clicked and its upload status in progress bar  with the help of angular. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use bootsrap progress bar or any angularjs plugin.. and rest it all depends on your logic applying for uploading.

Comment: This question is asked before ,so please try to find answers yourself before asking it on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but may be all those posts don't solve that purpose what exactly I want as I am a beginner in angular and wants more specific help.

Comment: its ok .but try to upload files without progress bar then implement progress bar..and you have freedom to ask questions as much as you can so that others will learn from them but also try to learn from other questions.

Comment: yup I know will do that from next time :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are various plugins you can use for file upload with progress bar. I particularly like jquery.form.js.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html

I found a link with working example and its integration with angularjs.

http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/a-directive-to-manage-file-upload-in-an-angularjs-application/

Comment: surely, I'll try this.