# How to upload a file with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file with AngularJS. This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
<button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(){
    var file = $scope.myFile;
    var uploadUrl = "http://admin.localhost/images/patanjali/";
    VariantService.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
};

VariantService.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(){
        alert ('success');
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
}
```

Although I can see the ('success') alert in my service, the file is not saving in the location provided in controller.

Can someone help me? What is missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [File Upload using angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)

Comment: _file is not saving_ - Well, that's a server-side problem, isn't it? It would be a good idea to tell us what library you use. Where does `file-model` come from?

Comment: What are you using server side to handle the saving of the file? To me it sounds like you are receiving and error there but have a good design in place so that it is swallowed or logged service side but still returns 200 to the client. This is good for security reasons. What we do is attach an error property to the response object and check if it is null to verify success. If it's not there was an error and the application reacts appropriately. If you let us know what you are using on the backend we can get a better idea of how to help.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like you're using [code from this jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/) for your app:

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);
```

While properly configured, this is only for posting data from the client side; the server also needs to be configured to accept/save the data. How you do this depends on your back-end tech stack.

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue. I tried following code and my problem was solved.

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
    },
    data: data,
    transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
            formData.append(key, value);
        });
        var headers = headersGetter();
        delete headers['Content-Type'];
        return formData;
    }
}

$http(req)
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.Models = response;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        alert(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$scope.setFiles = function (element) {
    $scope.$apply(function (scope) {
        $scope.files = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
            scope.files.push(element.files[i])
        }
    });
};

$scope.uploadFile = function() {
    var fd = new FormData();

    for (var i in $scope.files) {
        fd.append('file', $scope.files[i])
    }

    $http.post('http://admin.localhost/images/patanjali', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        }
    })
    .then(function successCallback(response) {
        
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        
    });
};
```

```html
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js'></script>
<input type="file" valid-file ng-model-instant id="fileToUpload" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)" />
<button ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AngularJs modules for file uploader.The modules are very useful and very comfortable.

1) https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

2) https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: Can you please share the links for that?

Comment: These are good modules, I've used both, but won't solve the problem the OP is experiencing. He's successfully handling the upload on the client side but seems to have a server side issue.