# java angularjs spring file upload

Tags: html, angularjs, spring, amazon-web-services, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to a server using angularjs and Spring (to Amazon AWS).
I checked a couple of posts on uploading with the first one and the latter but I still can't get the both to work together.

[File Upload using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)

[How to upload a file with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077947/how-to-upload-a-file-with-angularjs)

Checked also youtube for tutorials, found Black Cloud, Brent Aureli's channel and I just cannot figure it out.

You have to be authenticated in my webapp to send post requests, but I am getting errors also when I'm logged in.

Would be extremely grateful for some help.

This is my html form:

```
<form>
<input type="file" file-model="file">
<button ng-click="submit()" type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```

Directive for the file-model:

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element,attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                })
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

Controller:

```
.controller('UploadController', ['$scope', 'multipartForm', function($scope, multipartForm) {
    $scope.file = {}; 
    $scope.submit = function() {
        var uploadUrl = '/uploadtest';
        multipartForm.post(uploadUrl, $scope.file);
    }       
}])
```

Service for multipartForm:

```
.service('multipartForm', ['$http', function($http){
    this.post = function(uploadUrl, data) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        for(var key in data) {
            fd.append(key, data[key]);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
    }
}])
```

Spring Endpoint:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/storage/")
public class BucketController {

    private AmazonClient amazonClient;

    @Autowired
    public BucketController(AmazonClient amazonClient) {
        this.amazonClient = amazonClient;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadtest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file) {
        System.out.println("Uploading file!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        return this.amazonClient.uploadFile(file);
    }  
}
```

Error that I'm getting in the browser:

> angular.js:15018 Possibly unhandled rejection: 
>   {"data":{"timestamp":1537033312586,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException","message":"Required request part 'file' is not present","path":"/uploadtest"},
>   "status":400,
>   "config":{"method":"POST","transformResponse":[null],
>   "jsonpCallbackParam":"callback",
>   "headers":{"Accept":"application/json, 
>   text/plain, */*",
>   "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest",
>   "Authorization":
>   "Basic c3p5bW9uc3R1c3pla0BnbWFpbC5jb206dGVzdA==",
>   "X-XSRF-TOKEN":"395d1e27-a6ee-4948-b673-39d31902e1ae"},
>   "url":"/uploadtest","data":{}},
>   "statusText":"","xhrStatus":"complete"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception occurred due the missing query param 'file' which is not presented.
And in spring endpoint you should not receive a file request in Request param!

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/uploadtest", consumes = "multipart/form-data",method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
        public String uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest  request) throws Exception{

      try {
            MultipartFile multipartFile1 = request.getFile("file");
            if (multipartFile1 != null) {
                 String file1 = multipartFile1.getOriginalFilename();
                 InputStream inputStream = multipartFile1.getInputStream();
                // do whatever 
            }
         } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    return null;
}
```

And in Service for multipartForm change the headers content-type to : multipart/form-data

Hope this would Help!!

Comment: thanks a lot Ravikumar for the help!! with your advice, the frontend started to communicate with the spring controller :) 
unfortunately it is not the end of the issues.

I added the attribute name="file" in my form. Deleted @RequestMapping("/storage/") from the controller.

The controler is getting now the request, but when I try to get the file:
request.getFile("file")
It appears to be null.

When changing to multipart/form-data in services I have to set up boundaries and I'm not sure how to handle with that.

So it's communicating now but I cannot get the file from the request.

Comment: @szark did you try sending like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722093/send-multipart-form-data-files-with-angular-using-http

Comment: hi Ravikumar, I did some more searching and I found a working piece of code for me, I googled: grokonez Spring AngularJs MultipartFile application to download/upload files.
I just need to do a couple more tutorials, to get a better understanding of how the communication between angularjs and spring works, especially for file upload.
Thanks for the help again! :)