# Angular and file upload

Tags: java, angularjs

I have this situation.
Make a request to upload file with angular-upload-file:

```
var onBeforeUploadItem = function(item) {
item.formData.push({test:'test'});
        };

        var _emptyQueue = function(){
            $scope.uploader.clearQueue();
            $scope.uploader.formData = [];
        };

        var onAfterAddingAll = function(addedFileItems) {
            $scope.uploader.uploadAll();
        };

        var _initUploader = function(){

            $scope.uploader =  new FileUploader({
                url: (restServiceUrl),
                isHTML5 : true
            });
            $scope.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = onBeforeUploadItem;
            $scope.uploader.onAfterAddingAll = onAfterAddingAll;

            _emptyQueue();
        };
```

The request contain the file but List items = upload.parseRequest(service.getHttpServletRequest()) is empty.
Help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ng input file is not allowed for use ng-model.

> Not every feature offered is available for all input types. Specifically, data binding and event handling via ng-model is unsupported for input[file].

[Detail](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input).

You can take **file path** and use with Jquery File Upload functions.

This will help you:
[File Upload using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)