# How to send image to server on AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to send image to server with some additional data. My issue is that the image is not getting saved on server where other recordings are.

below is my **.html** code :

```
<div class="widget uib_w_4 d-margins" data-uib="media/file_input" data-ver="0">
   <input type="file" name="image" id="image" 
      accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" 
      ng-model="image" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
</div>
<div class="widget uib_w_5 d-margins" data-uib="media/text" data-ver="0">
   <div class="widget-container left-receptacle"></div>
   <div class="widget-container right-receptacle"></div>
   <div>
      <p>Username:</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS code**

```
< script >
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.SendData = function()
    var data = $.param({
        image: $scope.image,
        username: $scope.username,
    });

    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
                charset = utf - 8;
                '
        }
    }
    var param = getParameterByName('id');
    $http.post('myrurl.php', data, config)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        window.location.href = 'view.html';
    })
        .error(function(data, status, header, config) {
        alert('Please retry');
    });
};
}); 
< /script>
```

I tried to to print the value in PHP using print_r($_REQUEST);

The value of image is null.

*How can I send my image to the server?*

Comment: how do you handle things on the server side ?

Comment: server code is fine i tried to check via printing request by image value is blank

Comment: i use a separate enpoint on the server for the image upload only. The user has to  upload the image first, then send the form data.. But either way, I prep the image as a formData before sending it to the server

Comment: can u create fiddle example or guide me sample url, but i do not want to send as two request

Comment: check the third answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy. A good approach can be to Base64 encode the image, then send that Base64 to the server; the best part is that PHP natively supports decoding Base64.

You can do something like:

```
<!-- In your HTML file -->
<input type="file" id="file" /> 
<input type="submit" ng-click"uploadFile" value="Upload File"/>
```

Then, in your JavaScript:

```
$("#file").on('change', function(event) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function( loadEvent ) {

        $scope.fileData = loadEvent.target.result;
        $scope.$apply();

    };

    reader.readAsDataURL( event.target.files[0] );

});

$scope.uploadFile = function() {

    if ( $scope.fileData === null || $scope.fileData === "" || !($scope.fileData) ) {
        alert("No file has been uploaded");
        return;
    }


    var dtx = eval("(" + atob($scope.fileData.substring("data:application/json;base64,".length)) + ")");

    $http.get( 'yourScript.php?data=' + encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify(dtx) ) ).then( function(response) {

        if( response.data.status_code == 200 ) {

            // Done!

        } else { ERROR }

    });

};
```

Lastly, in your PHP file you can:

```
$imageData = base64_decode( $_GET[ 'data' ] ); // Now you have a binary image file. Do whatever you want!
```

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about the error? Also, remember that this code is just an example. You HAVE to edit it for your needs.

Comment: Works perfectly on my machine! Wait. Have you tried to debug it? Have you included jQuery?

Comment: That is the full code, you need to edit it according to your needs. I am just giving you with the info which is required to set the ball rolling.

Comment: @ weirdpanda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315615/how-to-upload-the-image-in-public-folder-and-retrieve-it-in-angularjs-mean-stack