# how to upload the image in public folder and retrieve it in Angularjs MEAN STACK

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack, image-uploading

i'm using angularjs i'm trying to do upload image operation. but i am not able to store image in my local path .and i want to store the image path into my db also i'm using mongodb  upload image operation. but i am not able to store image and retrieve from in my local path .Anyone help how to do this functionality

## My code

```
<html>

   <head>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body ng-app = "myApp">

    <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
    <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
</div>

      <script>  
      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);
        var uploadUrl = "/public/fileUpload";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };

}]);

      </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

## my Error Message

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Delivery%20Architecture.jpg
```

Comment: cant you use library?

Comment: you just want to upload a folder and retrieve ?

Comment: yes i upload the image into public folder and store into db that path and i retrieve it

Comment: any idea @Sajeetharan

Comment: did you find solution

Comment: no yar @ Sajeetharan

Comment: chk my fiddle first time it's comes after it's not working

Comment: where is the foddle?

Comment: sorry mymistake that pblm i solved my next one is 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368942/how-to-refresh-input-type-file-in-angularjs

Comment: @Sajeetharan did u see that

Comment: ya checking ! no clude

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513345/how-to-search-by-display-text-in-html-column-in-angularjs

Help@Sajeetharan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694605/how-to-switch-controller-values-from-ng-include-in-angularjs @Sajeetharan Help kindly check my coed and give a solution