# how to search by display text in html column in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

hi all i am using angularjs Mean Stack . now i bind the data in html table using ng-repeat it's work's nice and i have add one functionality name is called filter option but its not woking because i stored id values into db but when i bind show the values related to that id now in db there is id and show related values now filter working based on that id only not filtered by showing text i need filter by showing values
Thanks Help

## code

```
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list" >
       <thead>
        <tr>
     <th style="width: 25%" align="center">
       <a href="" ng-click="orderByField='RoleName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Name</a>
</th>
   
 <th style="width: 30% " align="center">
 <a href="" ng-click="orderByField='IsActive'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">IsActive?</a>
  </th>
  
    </tr>
 </thead>
  
<tbody>
 <tr>
 <td>
  <input type="text" id="RoleNameID" ng-model="Manage_Role1.RoleName" placeholder="search" class="searchbox" />
  </td>
   
</tr>
 <tr dir-paginate="Manage_Role in Manage_Roleser | itemsPerPage:8 | filter:Manage_Role1 | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort " ng-class-odd="'odd'">
  <td >
 <span e-ng-change="applyHighlight($data)" editable-text="Manage_Role.RoleName" ng-attr-title="{{Manage_Role.RoleName}}"e-form="rowform" >
  {{ Manage_Role.RoleName || 'empty' }}
 </span>
 </td>
   </span>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
  </div>
</table>
```

Here i stored the role id into db but i will show name based that id it's wokring fine but filter woking based id i want filter based displayed values

Comment: are you there ? question is not clear

Comment: i db i stored id like 1,2,3 but i show in screen that means like in html table i bind that related id values example 1 related value is Admin means i show admin in table but in admin id will stored .so i set filter that column means filter is working based id  not working Admin text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538460/angularjs-meanstack-refresh-function-not-working-in-ie11

@Sajeetharan  Help it's Urgent