# AngularJS factory function undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

I've been looking over this problem for the past 3 hours now and I'm extremely confused. The apache2 error logs say that the php script is being run, however I'm getting a an error from my factory when it's called.

```
TypeError: InputUpload.uploadImage(...) is undefined
```

I don't see how the javascript even gets that far to run the php script when the firefox debugger says it isn't defined...

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs
app.factory("API", function ($http) {
    return {
    uploadImage: function (image) {
        $http.post('/js/upload_image.php', image);
    }
    }
});

app.controller("MainController", ['$scope', '$http', 'API', function($scope, $http, 'API') {
    $scope.imageUrl = "";

    $scope.template = "";

    $scope.templates = [];

    $scope.templates.push("select an option...");
    $scope.templates.push("MakeGray");
    $scope.templates.push("Canny");

    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];

    $scope.add = function() {
    alert("HELLO");
    var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    var r = new FileReader();
    r.onloadend = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;

        API.uploadImage(data)
        .success(function (imgUrl) {
            $scope.imageUrl = imgUrl;
        })
        .error (function (error) {
        });
    }

    r.readAsBinaryString(f);
    }
});
```

Comment: there shouldn't have ' in function parameter `'API'` .. remove `'` from `API` . that's may be typo right ?

Comment: are you using any lazy loading functionality in your angular?

Comment: The code I posted is all the angularJS I'm using in my website, I'm also using just the angularJS min file.

Comment: do changes as `app.controller("MainController", ['$scope', '$http', 'API', function($scope, $http, API)`

Comment: Just tried it, still the same

Comment: Additionally, try using JsHint, and JsLint, because you `.js` file has errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return $http promise :

```
app.factory("API", function ($http) {
    return {
        uploadImage: function (image) {
           //add return her 
           return $http.post('/js/upload_image.php', image);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That got rid of the undefined part but now I'm dealt with an even bigger problem xD

Error: Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsBinaryString does not implement interface Blob.

Comment: nvm I forgot to undo a stupid change before adding in what you suggested, error message is gone now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    app.controller("MainController", ['$scope', '$http', 'InputUpload', 'API', function($scope, $http, API) {
//your code here..........
```

Comment: Adding return in app.factory removed the error message saying it was undefined. However there is a new problem that popped up and I'm not sure why...

I'm trying to upload an image to my webserver and I followed

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs

And it still isn't working...

Comment: error in post request or in factory method?
actually I am java developer and we use servlet  for image saving.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in controller injection.

In your controller replace it to

```
.controller("MainController", ['$scope', '$http', 'API', function($scope, $http, API) {
```

and the call your function `API.uploadImage(img)`