# base64 encoded image not displaying

Tags: angularjs, base64

So I was testing my code to see if my uploaded image was converted to base64 successfully. When I did alert(data) however I found that it was a garbled mess of unknown characters. I wanted to have the popup message contain the base64 string so I could put it into an online base64 decoder to confirm that the uploaded image was correct.

Afterwards I want to give the file name + base64 string to my php script which then writes it to the server.

However this is what I got

https://i.stack.imgur.com/089Gq.png

Here is the code that is supposed to take the given image and convert it.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs
app.factory('API', function ($http) {   
    return {
    uploadImage: function (image) {
        return $http.post('/js/upload.php', image);
    }
    }
});

app.controller('MainController',['$scope', '$http', 'API', function($scope, $http, API) {
    $scope.imageUrl = "";
    $scope.template = "";
    $scope.templates = [];

    $scope.templates.push("select an option...");
    $scope.templates.push("MakeGray");
    $scope.templates.push("Canny");
    $scope.templates.push("HSV");

    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];

    $scope.add = function() {

    var f = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];  // name of image
    var files = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files;
    var r = new FileReader();

    r.onload = function(event){
        console.log(event.target.result);
    }

    r.onloadend = function(e) {

        var data = e.target.result;
        alert(data);

        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("fileToUpload", f,f.name);

        API.uploadImage(formData)
        .success(function (imgUrl) {
            $scope.imageUrl = imgUrl;
        })
        .error (function (error) {
        });
    }

    r.readAsBinaryString(f);
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading as `BinaryString` is sure to give you unprintable characters. If you want it as base64 encoded (specifically to display as image) then you need to read it as `DataURL`. Following will definitely help you:

```
r.readAsDataURL(f);
```

For more information on `FileReader` consult <kbd>[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader)</kbd>.

Here is working <kbd>[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amantur/wpL0wvaq/1/)</kbd> to play with different read types.

Comment: Thank you for response, I will try this out and respond back.

Are you an angularJS developer?

Comment: I tried to use 

$("#img1").prop("src",data);

in my angularJS but it was giving the following error.

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 

$("#img1").prop("src", data);

Also, how are you getting away with checking if v is equal to something on line 12 in the JS if you haven't defined v before hand?

Comment: well, yes I'm working on and learning angular js. now about your second comment. 1. I don't think this is the angular way of doing it. If you set `imageUrl` to value read from file (that is `event.target.result`) it should reflect. 2. `v` is already defined before the `onloandend` is called. Someone can explain it by using closure/variable scoping etc etc...

Comment: Ok nvm I was being dumb and forgot that I needed to have jQuery in my html sources. Thank you so much for your help, this problem is something I've been working on for a while.

Also, is there a way to scale the image to a max height / width? Like it must always be within a 800x800 border?

Comment: I've updated fiddle to set height/width to 250px using css class for img element. you can try that.

Comment: Wow, I love you. You solved a problem in 5 minutes that a weeks worth of asking on stackoverflow couldn't do. Thanks a bunch! Is there a way to contact you in the future if I need help?

Comment: ha ha I think mentioning using @ helps :)
Glad I was able to help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98572/discussion-between-zypps987-and-thevillageidiot).

Comment: I was able to find a way to make the 2 images side by side, but any idea of how to make them a little lower on the page? 


Screenshot of website
imgur.com/jS1vEKq

Here is the html
pastebin.com/ZZt4MBPY