# How to pass base64 encoded image to php?

Tags: php, angularjs, base64, image-uploading

I was wondering how I would get php script to retrieve my base64 encoded image then write to server? I tried doing a post dump from my php script and I keep getting a response that it is empty. I've tried following a few other stackoverflow guides on this but none of them use a factory afaik.

js

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs
app.factory('API', function ($http) {  
    return {
    uploadImage: function (image) {
            return $http.post('/js/upload.php', image);
    }
    }
});

app.controller('MainController',['$scope', '$http', 'API', function($scope, $http, API) {
    $scope.imageUrl = "";
    $scope.template = "";
    $scope.templates = [
    'select an option...',
    'MakeGray',
    'Canny'
    ];

    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];

    $scope.add = function() {

    var f = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];  // name of image
    var files = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files;
    var r = new FileReader();

    r.onload = function(event){
            console.log(event.target.result);
    }

    r.onloadend = function(e) {

            var data = e.target.result;
            var formData = new FormData();     

        $("#img1").prop("src", data);
        $("#img2").prop("src", data);

            formData.append("fileToUpload", f,f.name);

            API.uploadImage(formData)
        .success(function (imgUrl) {
            $scope.imageUrl = imgUrl;
        })
        .error (function (error) {
        });
    }

    r.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}]);
```

php

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])){    
  $errors= array();        
  $file_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];  
  $file_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png");        
  if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
    $errors[]="image extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }
  if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[]='File size cannot exceed 2 MB';
  }              
  if(empty($errors)==true){
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../uploads/".$file_name);
    echo " uploaded file: " . "images/" . $file_name;
  }else{
    print_r($errors);
  }
}
else{
  $errors= array();
  $errors[]="No image found";
  print_r($errors);
}
?>
```

Comment: you're not doing a file upload. you're just copying a couple bits of data out of the file input and stuffing them into a new form, without ever telling that new form that it's a file input. do a `var_dump($_POST)` and you'll probably see `fileToUpload` in there.

Comment: I tried that in my php and I got nothing.

Comment: then check `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])`, make sure is says post. if it doesn't, then something cause a redirect. try adding a couple garbage fields to the request and see if they come through anywhere.

Comment: the file object you trying to pass will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" because you are not going to process file in client side, then try to disable content-type

Comment: @Marc B I just tried var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])  and got the following string(4) "POST", not sure what that means though.

Comment: just means that the script was invoked as a POSt requests, which is good. there's been plenty of cases where people had a bad rewrite causing their post to be redirected into GET, which also killed everything in $_POST.

Comment: How would I access the contents of the $_SERVER? It would appear there's 4 items, so would it be

    for(int i = 0; i < $_SERVER.length; i++){
        echo $_SERVER.at(i);
    }

? I know that's not write but I'm still very new to php, I'm more familiar with c.

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER);to debug, and to use: foreach($_SERVER as $key => $val) echo "$key : $val\n";

Comment: Here is the echo for what you just told me 

http://i.imgur.com/ZYj7Xpt.png

The post data

http://i.imgur.com/5qhT4G0.png

I see that the base64 is being passed to the php, but why is it garbled garbage and not the base64 as it is shown in my javascript? How would I fix this?

Comment: because your "data" variable containing base64 is not included to your FormData object, formData.append("fileToUpload", data) instead of f, but the php code is writed to a file input upload.. it will not work with base64 encoded image.  (API.uploadimage is your own code ?)

Comment: are you really need to having image base64 encoded ? why don't you use a standard input ?

Comment: Yes, but I am very new to angularJS and webdev in general, I sort of got lucky with it working at all.

Comment: I found this to be the one solution that worked vs the other ways of uploading an image with the current implementation I have with the dropdown menu. :/ if you know of a better way I'm all ears.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98585/discussion-between-mtroy-and-zypps987).

Answer (score 0):

Angular have a particularity in concern the uploading.

First, you have to kno, angular's default **transformRequest** function will try to **serialize our FormData object**, so we override it with the identity function to leave the data intact.

Next, the default content-type header for POST requests is "application/json", so you must to change this because you want to upload a file.
By setting **'Content-Type': undefined**, the browser sets the Content-Type to multipart/form-data himself and fills in the correct boundary.
Manually setting **'Content-Type': multipart/form-data** will fail to fill in the boundary parameter of the request.

Look about others possible issues : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Now you can get you image from $_POST global array of PHP.

Fixed code

```
    uploadImage: function (formData)
    {
        return $http.post('js/upload.php', formData,
        {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        });
    }
```

Note:

That the below service uses the FormData object which is not supported by IE9 and earlier.

Comment: what can i use to get data on other php side ? i am using cakphp