# Angular JS image uploader advice

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, photo-upload

I'm new to Angular JS and want to make create an image uploader using it, but I'm not sure where to start. Are there any tools out there to help me, or any advice you can give?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are many existing modules to upload image with angular (or upload file) :

-[angular-upload-file](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)

-[ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Both are well documented so it may be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a previous StackOverflow Q & A that provides some good resources for AngularJS image/file uploaders:

[File Upload using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)

Good Luck!