# AngularJs File Upload ()

Tags: angularjs

I want to create an file upload button with send some parameters 
Here is my code: 
it is not working for me.
could you help me?

```
<pre>
   <input type="file" name="file" 
    onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files,project._id, activity._id, action.name, document._id)"/>
</pre>
```

Comment: I also try  to fire an another function to get the param value


<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files);fileLoad(project._id, activity._id, action.name, document._id)"/>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Upload using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Insert this HTML into your code where onFileSelect function will be called when file is selected.

```html
<div class="col-xs-2 padding_sm" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files,$index)"
 multiple accept="image/*"></div>
```