# Uploading a file and saving it to a folder- Mean stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am trying to develop a simple web application using mean stack. I want to take a file input from the user and save the uploaded file into a folder(Ex: /home/user/Desktop/files). Can someone please help me on how to write the controller to do this.

My ui code is as follows.

```
      <h5>Upload file</h5>
      <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
           <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
             Browse&hellip; <input type="file" multiple>
           </span>
         </span>
         <input type="text" id="file" class="form-control">
      </div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
```

It looks like this.

[image]

When the user uploads the file. I want the file to appear in the `input` field will `file` id and when he clicks on the `submit` button the file should get saved in the given folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Upload using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)

Comment: The main thing that I want to achieve is displaying the name of the file in the input element with file id. I also want to save the file locally into a particular folder.

Comment: ah sorry, my mistake. I missed the subtlety of your question.