# Printing header of CSV file - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv

I am new to angular JS and I am trying to work out the following.

I am taking a CSV file as input from the user and sending it to the controller on clicking a submit button.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"ng-click="Input(File)">Submit</button>
```

My controller is as follows

```
$scope.Input = function(file) 
{
  var t = file.toString().split("\n");
  var head = t[0].split(",");
  console.log(head);
}
```

I am trying to print the header of the uploaded CSV file. But in the console I am getting `["[object File]"]`. Can someone help me on how to modify the code to get the header of uploaded csv file.

Comment: use filereader http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs

Comment: can you please tell me on what changes I have to make in the code?

Answer (score 0):

you can install this npm package .
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-grape

```
CsvGrape.getCsvData(event).then((_response)=>{
      let header=_response.Headers; //header array
      
    },(reject)=>{
      log
    });
```