# Angular JS file upload to a hosted server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I recently started developing an application in Angular JS and Node Js, it's completely a new stuff for me, I am right now into tricky situation where I want to upload the images or files to a folder where my Angular application is hosted, I am using node js as REST API which is running on the different server whereas Angular JS part is hosted on the different server, all I want to do is to save files uploaded by the users to Angular JS server, I don't know exactly how achieve it. I can make calls to my Node js server and pass file to it and save it their, but my problem is that node js app hosted somewhere else and my angular js is app host somewhere, I want to save my files to angular js server folder

Any suggestions and help from you guys would be much appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) and [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload), there are other questions already answered.

[File Upload using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand my scenario I have two different servers.... My requests are handled by node js app whereas front end part is written in angular js which on the different server, all I want to do is to save file on angular hosted server not on the node server.... If I am not wrong, to upload a file we need make a request to the server and backend server is node js which is somewhere else where I don't want to save files... I am thinking of sending files to node server and from there I will make a use of ftp call through node to save files to my angular hosted server... It's quite inconvenient method but I feel I can achieve what I want from it...