# AngularJS WebAPI (C#) File upload

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

Uploading a file (including content) 
Environment: HTML, AngularJS, WebAPI
Current implmentation: Call the API method in the form's action. In the API controller listen to the HttpContext.Current.Request and get the file in the server side
Issues: The URL is redirected to form's action method therefore need to manually redirect back to last url. In this process authentication is lost.

Better way to implement?

Comment: "in this process authentication is lost" - is this a requirement or a problem you've encountered with?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs

Comment: its a problem.. auth details is stored in rootscope and details are getting cleared in redirection

Comment: Hold on, do you store your authentication data in the scope?

Comment: yes, data is in rootscope

Comment: But AngularJS scope is stored client-side, doesn't it mean that an intruder can forge auth data?