# How to Bind Images into Angular

Tags: angularjs

Here i want to up-lode image into sql service all data is binding why image path not taking

**Html code**

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="password" />
<input type="file" name="ImageFile" ng-model="ImageFile" class="form-control">
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Register" ng-click="BtnLogin()" />

**Angular.Js**


$scope.BtnLogin = function () {
            var save = {
                Image: $scope.ImageFile,
                Email: $scope.Email,
                password: $scope.password
            }

        var xxx = MyserviceContect.DataSave(save)

        xxx.then(function () {

        })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Upload using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)

Comment: do u have any idea of complte details plz give me  uri