# input type file is unable to get the file name with file type in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, openfiledialog, input-type-file

I am creating a web app in which i have an input field

`<input type="file" ng-model="getfilename" />`

and  a button

`<button ng-click="clickfordetails()">Click Here!</button>`

and a paragraph tag`<P>{{file}}</p>`
when a user clicks on button after entering a file from input field he should get the file name in `{{file}}`

and here is my controller for the same

```
$scope.clickfordetails=function() {
    $scope.file=$scope.getfilename;
}
```

but i am unable to get the file name when i edit my controller to this

```
$scope.clickfordetails=function() {
    console.log($scope.getfilename);
}
```

the value in my console(google chrome) is `Undefined`

how i need to do this??

Comment: no it is not working thats why i asked question here sir

Comment: You cant access file using ng-model

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the below directive

```
directive('customFileInput', [function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('change', function  (evt) {
                var files = evt.target.files;
                scope.filename=files[0].name
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: where i need to use directive?

Comment: put the abode directive on your project then modify your input with <input type="file" custom-file-input> on your controller you will get filename on variable '$scope.filename'

Comment: please upvote my question if you think it is a deserving one