# I want to upload file using angular 6 and connect that with API, but its taking default type "application/json", i want to change that to file format

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am doing in this way:

```
fileUpload(data){

      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('file', data);
         headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/file');
      let file_upload =  {
        headers: headers,
      };

    console.log(data, "file upload")
    return this.httpClient.post('api/data_loader/file/', file_upload);
  }
```

**Error**:

> Unsupported media type "application/json" in request.

**Expected Result**: I want to change this default media type to file format.

**Note: I am using Angular6.**

Comment: Just a heads-up. The Content-Type `application/file` is not a valid Media-Type, see : http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml .I assume either Angular or your Service understands that and maps it to json. You aren't even sending a file anyways. The proper way to send files is in the answer provided by Sachila.

Comment: Hi Jyoti, this question/answer on Stack overflow might be helpful [File Upload using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use the form data in order to upload a file.

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', data, data.name); 
this.httpClient.post('api/data_loader/file/', formData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your data is a formData,if not then create form data something like that before calling httpClient....

```
const data= new FormData();
data.append('file', data);  //note that this data is file not json data...
```

if your are sending formData then below function should work...

```
fileUpload(data){


          let headers = new Headers({ 
    });

//add any header if you need to for authentication 

return this.httpClient.post('api/data_loader/file/',data, headers);
}
```