# uploading multiple images on php

Tags: php

I'm using drop zone and angularjs. I want to upload multiple images and send it to the server. I'm trying to process my upload on custom rather than to process on the drop zone.  I'm storing all accepted files on drop zone to ng-model so that I will grab all images and upload to the server. my problem is how to loop array images on php. Any idea how to achieve this?

js

```
 $scope.saveform = function(){
  var fd=new FormData();
  console.log($scope.info.allimages);

  fd.append('type','form');
  fd.append('file',$scope.info.allimages);

    $http.post(httprequest, fd,{
          transformRequest: angular.identity,
          headers: {'Content-Type': undefined, 'Process-Data': false}
      }
  ).then(function(response) {


  });
}
```

js console.log result:

```
[File {upload=Object, status="queued", ...}, File {upload=Object, status="queued", ...}]
```

dropzone config:

```
  $scope.dropzoneConfig2 = {
    'options': {
        url : httprequest,
        acceptedFiles : 'image/jpeg, images/jpg, image/png',
        addRemoveLinks : true,
        parallelUploads : 20,
        maxFiles: 20,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        autoProcessQueue : false,
        init: function () {
              var vm = this;
        }
    },
    'eventHandlers': {
          'addedfile': function(file) {
              $scope.info.allimages = this.getAcceptedFiles();
          },
          'removedfile': function(file) {
          },
          'sending': function (file, xhr, formData) {
          },
          'success': function (file, response) {
          }
     }

  }
```

php:

```
if($_POST['type']=='form'){
echo json_encode($_POST['file']));}
```

php result:

```
"[object File],[object File]"
```

Comment: kindly use `print_r($_POST['file'])` in php file and see the output

Comment: same on my post php result. "[object File],[object File]".

Comment: try this posts may be you get an idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/31363033/9128487

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
for($count = 0; $count<count($_FILES["files"]["name"]); $count++)
{
    $_FILES["file"]["name"] = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$count];
    $_FILES["file"]["type"] = $_FILES["files"]["type"][$count];
    $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$count];
    $_FILES["file"]["error"] = $_FILES["files"]["error"][$count];
    $_FILES["file"]["size"] = $_FILES["files"]["size"][$count];
}
```