# Using angular js post to django back end yields a 414 error

Tags: angularjs, django

```
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
            var fileData = reader.result;

            $http({
                url: 'rs/submit',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'img': fileData,
                    'query': query,
                    'limit': limit
                }
            })
            .then(function successCallback(response) {

            }, function errorCallback(response) {

            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('submitFileInput').files[0]);
```

I'm trying to send a image to my django back end using angular js as you can see above, but I get a error in the back end that says:

[22/Dec/2018 12:59:34] "POST /dynamic-mosaic/rs/submit HTTP/1.1" 200 4

[22/Dec/2018 12:59:34] code 414, message Request-URI Too Long

[22/Dec/2018 12:59:34] "" 414 -

I thought POST can send requests of almost any size, the image isnt even that big like 1-2MB

Anyone knows the cause? Maybe I'm not using angular js $http service properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving `Blob` type is a bit different

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('img', reader.result);
fd.append('query', query);
fd.append('limit', limit);
                
$http.post('rs/submit', fd, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
}).then(...)
```

Probably you should also consider [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs)

UPD: here is an external [resource](https://www.uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs/) for your consideration

> Angular’s default `transformRequest` function will try to serialize
> our FormData object, so we override it with the identity function to
> leave the data intact.
>
> Angular’s default Content-Type header for POST
> and PUT requests is application/json, so we want to change this, too.
> By setting ‘Content-Type’: undefined, the browser sets the
> Content-Type to multipart/form-data for us and fills in the correct
> boundary. Manually setting ‘Content-Type’: multipart/form-data will
> fail to fill in the boundary parameter of the request.

Comment: this works but can you explain me what {
                  transformRequest: angular.identity,
                  headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
               } does? it seem not to work without these

Comment: hey, added an additional resource, check it out