# read file content on form input in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a JSON file in my HDD, how can I read the content of this file when I select it with input field?

I have to read the content and send content as data in some API!

I need something like this :

```
<input type="file" id="dashboardExportedFile">
<button type="button" ng-click="importDashboard">Import</button>
<script>
  $scope.importDashboard = function (
    var content = $("#dashboardExportedFile").content
    console.log(content);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at this Stackoverflow question, it may provide you with the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a Filereader. Follow my Link to see an working example with .txt File. Hope u can use it:
[JSFiddle][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/6aG4x/
```