# Upload FIle with Angular JS and PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to upload a file with Angular JS and PHP using a formdata object.

I would like to use key1 (data)  value to be JSON so I can pass the filename and user info etc. to the php script

I would like to use key2 (uploadFile), value to be the file being uploaded;

I can use POSTMAN to set a  key (named data) and add a value for some JSON data {"username" : "kk1"}
  then set a key (named uploadFile) and a value pointing to the test file. upload_test1.txt
  The PHP succeeds and the file, upload_test1.txt is uploaded and saved to the correct location.

When I run the test using Angularjs
  The PHP responds and says that the index **uploadFile does not exist**

The only thing i can think is that the file path is set incorrectly.

See snippets below

Any help would be appreciated

KNK53

Angular   username = "kk1"  id="1" and filename = "C:\temp\upload_test2.txt"
...
      bdy = {
            "username": username, "id": id };

```
   var fd = new FormData();

   `fd.append("data", JSON.stringify(bdy));
    fd.append("uploadFile", filename);

    $http.post(myurl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { "Content-Type": undefined,  "processData" : false }
    })
```

...

// the PHP echoes the json and then "from variable:kk1 " lines 1-3
// then error Notice: Undefined index: uploadFile        line 5
PHP

```
 1    $data = json_decode($_POST["data"],true);//should have a username  
 2    echo 'get file:' . $_POST["data"];
 3    echo 'from variable:' . $data["username"];

 4 echo '<br>';
 5 $user = $_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'];
echo 'filename:' . $user . '<br>';
echo 'dir:' . ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
$target_dir = "../uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . 'gotfile.txt';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
   echo 'move succeeded';
}
else
  echo 'move failed';
```

Comment: You are only sending the file _name_ in text form here, you are not performing an actual file upload.

Comment: _“The only thing i can think is that the file path is set incorrectly.”_ - sounds like you thought you could upload arbitrary files from the client by simply specifying the path to them yourself in code …? Of course you can’t, the user needs to actively select the file.

Answer (score 0):

I came to that conclusion as well.  I am new to WEB programming but have a lot of other programming experience.   The FormData object append method does not actually upload the file.

```
fd.append("uploadFile", filename);
```

Is it best to use a directive and then incorporate the FileReader object to read the file data??

OR

I see on other stack overflow threads

that some answers use a directive only to access the "FILES" property of the input element

```
    fd.append("file", element[0].files[0])   ??? does this actually append the file data
```

[File Upload using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs) 
   see marker 57 of this thread??

KNK53

Answer (score 0):

So I redid the functions

Using:
     `fd.append("file", element[0].files[0]`

This sends the information as $_FILE to PHP

Using  a filereader and the onreadend event:

```
 onreadend = function(tgt) {
    fdata = tgt.target.result;    
    fd.append("file", fdata);   
         .
         .
         .
 }

This approach sends the data to $_POST in PHP
```

KNK53

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="userName" />
<input type="file" your-directive ng-model="userFile" />
```

In your directive's `link` method:

```
element.bind('change', function(event) {
  scope.userFile = event.target.files[0]; // 'scope' here reefer to the scope where the model will be used to be posted, could be for example the parent scope (scope.$parent) or the root scope..., could even emit the new value too
});
```

In your controller, assuming your file is posted on a form submit event linked to the controller:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  ...
  formData.append('userName', $scope.userName);
  formData.append('userFile', $scope.userFile, $scope.userFile.name);
  ...
  $http({
    method: 'POST', 
    url: <apiUrl>, 
    data: formData, 
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} // <-- don't forget this
    ...
  }).then...
};
```

PHP:

```
$userName = $_POST['userName'];
$userFile = $_FILES['userFile'];
```

Sorry for the too many editings... got distracted