# Upload a zip file via input type file angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

I don't do angularjs daily, and I've tried to add a upload file button. It should only take .zip and 20 MB max. I did

***Try#1***

```
<input class="pull-right" type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" ngf-select="$ctrl.uploadFile()" ngf-pattern="'application/zip'" ngf-max-size="20MB">
```

***Try#2***

> Add `onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)"`

```
<input class="pull-right" type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" ngf-select="$ctrl.uploadFile()" ngf-pattern="'application/zip'" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)" ngf-max-size="20MB">
```

and my component file I have

```
this.uploadFile = {};
this.uploadFile.Iserror=false;


this.uploadFile = function(files) {    
    this.uploadFile.Iserror=false;



    console.log(files); //undefined
    


                   
    if(files[0].type!=="zip"){
        alert("Not a zip file.");
        this.uploadFile.Iserror=true;
        return false;
    }       
};
```

[image]

What do I need to do to access the file I selected ?

Comment: You'll need a package to help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20506037/1772933

Comment: We can’t use pure angular js or with vanilla js to solve this ?? I hope we don’t have to include others libraries for this one browse button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**input**

```
<input class="pull-right" type="file" ngf-max-size="20MB" ngf-select="$ctrl.uploadFile($file, $invalidFiles)" ngf-pattern="'*zip*'"/>
```

---

**component**

```
this.uploadFile = function(file, invalidFiles) {    
    console.log(file, invalidFiles);
};
```

---

**console**

[image]

---

**access**

```
console.log(file.name, file.size, file.type);
// ea8300-1.0.0.tar.gz 11980935 application/x-gzip
```