# Upload File using Angular and Django

Tags: python, django, angularjs, django-forms, django-uploads

So, I have a issue that i cant find a solution for. I am developing an application using Django where my front end has to be in angular-js. Now I am able to render forms and also post the data from the forms, but i have no idea how to upload a file using these forms.

This is my code:

in urls.py

```
url(r'^getter/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = "upload.html"))
url(r'^getter/test/', views.test, name = "thanks.html")
```

in views.py

```
def test(request):
   upload_form = uploadform(request.POST, request.FILES)
   data = json.loads(request.body)
   file_path = data.path
```

in forms.py

```
select_file = forms.FileField(label = "Choose File")
```

in my js file inside my controller

```
myapp.controller('abc', function ($scope, $http)
$scope.submit = function(){
var file = document.getElementById('id_select_file').value
var json = {file : string(file)}
$http.post('test/',json)
...success fn....
...error fn...
```

};
});

Now the issue is that if in my view if i do

```
f = request.FILES['select_file']
```

**I get error 'select_file' not found in MultiValueDict: {}**

probably the issue is that with the way am sending my post request am not sending all the meta data....please help me out with this i have spent the whole day looking for a solution but no avail.

PS: for some restriction policies I can not use Djangular so please give me solutions that donot use djangular. Thanks

Edit: **Applying file properties to the json that the server is receiving doesnt work either **

Comment: Don't know Django, but your json uses `file` and your view refers to `select_file` Is this correct?

Comment: @craigb yeah just edited my question. basically none od django's file methods or functions work when i use angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I found an efficient solution of how to send files to Django Forms with Angular $http.

**DIRECTIVE**

```
app.directive("filesInput", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function postLink(scope,elem,attrs,ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function(e) {
        var files = elem[0].files;
        ngModel.$setViewValue(files);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form ng-submit="send()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" ng-model="producer.name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="file" files-input ng-model="producer.video">
</form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.send = function(){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('video', $scope.producer.video[0]);
    fd.append("name", $scope.producer.name);

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/sendproducer/',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': undefined
        },
        data: fd,
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
}
```

**DJANGO VIEW FORM**

```
class ProducerView(View):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProducerView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request):
        form = ProducerForm(data = request.POST, files = request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return JsonResponse({"status": "success", "message": "Success"})
        return JsonResponse({"status": "error", "message": form.errors})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below snippet so that you can send usual data along with the file data from angular to django.

```
$scope.submit = function(){
    var fd = new FormData();
    datas = $("#FormId").serializeArray();
    // send other data in the form
    for( var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++ ) {
         fd.append(datas[i].name, datas[i].value);
        };
    // append file to FormData
    fd.append("select_file", $("#id_select_file")[0].files[0])
    // for sending manual values
    fd.append("type", "edit");
    url = "getter/test/",
    $http.post(url, fd, {
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
};
```

Now you will get `select_file` under `request.FILES` and other datas inside `request.POST` in your django view.

Comment: I tried the above snippet and it was working fine for me. I am not sure why it got down vote. It will be great if you can point-out the issue with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A combination of early posts with the correct Angular functions.

```
(function(app){
   app.controller("Name_of_Controller", function($scope, $http){
      $scope.submit = function(){
         var fd = new FormData();
         datas = $("#formID").serializeArray();
         for( var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++ ) {
            fd.append(datas[i].name, datas[i].value);
         };
        fd.append("selected_file", $("#file_id")[0].files[0])
        fd.append("type", "edit");
        url = "/results/",
        $http.post(url, fd, {
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data)
        }).catch(function (err) {});;
    };
});
})(App_name);
```

Answer (score -1):

I strongly suggest using a third party plugin such as [ngUpload](http://twilson63.github.io/ngUpload/) or [fileUploader](http://cgeers.com/2013/05/03/angularjs-file-upload/) to achieve this. What you are doing on the client does not look correct.

Also refer to [this SO thread on angularjs file uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979712/file-uploader-integration-for-angularjs?rq=1%20)

Comment: is there no way that we can use the file upload features of django while posting data using angular? Django File upload is simple and clean...